# Can sed be used to reverse only the first n characters of all the lines in a file?

Tags: sed

For example...

```
this is a line 2345
this is a line 1234
```

sed can reverse the lines (the numbers are the same length but the lines in the file are of different lengths):

```
5432 enil a si siht
4321 enil a si siht
```

Now can sed reverse (not extract) only the number so the file can be sorted on the number:

```
2345 enil a si siht
1234 enil a si siht
```

then reversing the first n characters again:

```
4321 enil a si siht
5432 enil a si siht
```

and then the entire line, sorts the entire file by the number at the end of the uneven lines:

```
this is a line 1234
this is a line 2345
```

Asking as I am unable to use sed to sort on the number at the end of a file's uneven lines.

Comment: Could you give me the input and the expected output? I don't really get what you want... Also could you attach your code?

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: so all the reversing stuff is because you want to sort based on number present in the line? use awk/perl/ruby for easier solution, or copy paste the number to starting line, sort and then remove it...

Comment: I suggest to take a look at [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Comment: Is this a sed  challenge, or why do you want to do it in sed?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(.{0})(.{4})/\1\n\2\n/;T;:a;s/\n(.)(.*\n)/\n\2\1/;ta;s/\n//g' file
```

This will reverse the first four characters of a line (providing the line has a least four characters).

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+)/\n&\n/;T;:a;s/\n(.)(.*\n)/\n\2\1/;ta;s/\n//g' file
```

This will reverse the first set of digits (one or more) on a line.

Combinations of the above can be used to reverse a part or a whole line.

Comment: Wow. This answer is amazing! I just wander why `(.{0})` in the first version. Can you explain it?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis This allows to reverse a particular part of  a  line e.g `sed -r 's/^(.{10})(.{4})/\1\n\2\n/;T;:a;s/\n(.)(.*\n)/\n\2\1/;ta;s/\n//g' file` will in the example reverse the word `line` to `enil` i.e. the next four characters after the first ten.

Comment: I got this, but why matching zero characters in your first line code? Does it change anything? I mean `(.{0})`always matches everywhere, doesn't it? So it's useless there, isn't it?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis does not change anything in this example, but I included it for pedogogical purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In my interpretation of your question, you have lines with varying numbers of words and a number at the end and you want to sort on the number at the end.  If so, consider this sample file:

```
$ cat File
this is a line 231
Another 312
a longer long with many words 123
```

To sort it numerically with sed, try:

```
$ sed -E 's/.* ([[:digit:]]+)$/\1 &/' File | sort -n | sed 's/^[[:digit:]]* //'
a longer long with many words 123
this is a line 231
Another 312
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your file does not contain a '#' character. You can insert such a character before the number, and specify it as a delimiter for sort, sort on that value, and remove it again:

```
cat tosort.txt | sed -r 's/ ([0-9]+)$/ #\1/' | sort -t'#' -k2 -n | sed 's/#//'
3 a longer long with many words 123
1 this is a line 231
2 Another 312
```

If your file does contain a #, you could chose another magic delimiter. 
If the input files change, you can test them before to not contain such an character, and one step further, automatically search for a useful character for that purpose.

I don't know why John deleted his answer, moving the number to the front, sort the file, and move it back again. Seems an even better solution.

Or do you really want to sort with sed?

To just resort the first 4 digits, you can use something like that:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9]) (.*)/\4\3\2\1 \5/' toresort.txt
```

For a given, bigger number of digits, you can generate such an expression partly or fully automatically.

```
rfec () { n=$1; echo -n $g;  if (( $n > 0 )) ; then  rfec $(( n - 1 )); fi ; x=$1; echo -n '\$'$((9-x)); }
rfec 9
([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])\$9\$8\$7\$6\$5\$4\$3\$2\$1\$0
```